# How to disable Autocomplete option in SSRS report Parameters?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtESV.png)How to disable Autocomplete option in SSRS report Parameters ?For Example we can disable autocomplete option in telerik textbox by setting the property AutoCompleteType="Disabled"

Comment: I don't think SSRS allows auto complete for parameters. Can you provide more details?

Comment: In my Case i have a Date type Parameter and random text is shown in suggestion box

Comment: This is not SSRS issue. Clear cache and form data from your browser and try.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have Available Values set for that parameter, 
right click on the [**From Date**] parameter in the design pane and click on [**Parameter Properties**], then navigate to the [**Available Values**] Tab and select **None**, that should fix your report.

Comment: I dont have any available values in my parameter properties.